# Reading a USB serial port-based scale in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, serial-port

We just switched from USB HID-based scales to serial-based scales. I am  having trouble retrieving data using JavaScript from these scales.

```
(async () => {
    const ports=await navigator.serial.getPorts();
    const myScale=ports[0];
    await myScale.open({ baudRate: 9600,dataBits:8,stopBits: 1, parity: `none`,flowControl: `none`});
    console.log(`myScale: `, myScale);
    const textDecoder = new TextDecoderStream();
    const readableStreamClosed = myScale.readable.pipeTo(textDecoder.writable);
    const reader = textDecoder.readable.getReader();

    // Listen to data coming from the serial device.
    while (true) {
        const { value, done } = await reader.read();
        if (done) {
            // Allow the serial port to be closed later.
            reader.releaseLock();
            break;
        }
        // value is a string.
        console.log(value);
    }
})();
```

`myScale` gets created correctly:

```
myScale:  
SerialPort {onconnect: null, ondisconnect: null, readable: ReadableStream, writable: WritableStream}
onconnect: null
ondisconnect: null
readable: ReadableStream
locked: false
[[Prototype]]: ReadableStream
writable: WritableStream
locked: false
[[Prototype]]: WritableStream
[[Prototype]]: SerialPort
close: ƒ close()
getInfo: ƒ getInfo()
getSignals: ƒ getSignals()
onconnect: (...)
ondisconnect: (...)
open: ƒ open()
readable: (...)
setSignals: ƒ setSignals()
writable: (...)
constructor: ƒ SerialPort()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "SerialPort"
get onconnect: ƒ onconnect()
set onconnect: ƒ onconnect()
get ondisconnect: ƒ ondisconnect()
set ondisconnect: ƒ ondisconnect()
get readable: ƒ readable()
get writable: ƒ writable()
[[Prototype]]: EventTarget
```

But everything comes to a halt when attempting to read the input from the scale:

```
const { value, done } = await reader.read();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here's the browser compatibility if this matters https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Serial/getPorts

Comment: @GetSet -- browser compatibility is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh...Unlike the previous HID-based scales, which gave a continual reading, the user needs to press the "Print" button on this scale to send the data.